# What does "vice president, European Union" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used these links but I couldn't figure out what she did at European Union because as far as I know, European Union has no President. How can there be a vice president.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/author/frances-g-burwell-phd
http://www.atlanticcouncil.org/about/experts/list/frances-g-burwell
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_European_Union

"It's going to be tough for the British. I think that they're going to find that it's very difficult to achieve what they want and to not be part of the single market," said Burwell, vice president, European Union, at the Atlantic Council.

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/29/heres-what-investors-should-expect-as-Brexit-begins-experts-say.html

Comment: It's not saying that she's Vice President **of** the European Union, she's Vice President at the Atlantic Council for European Union issues: http://www.atlanticcouncil.org/about/experts/list/frances-g-burwell

Comment: It is potentially relevant here that "vice president" as a job title in the business world has been subject to a lot of inflation in recent decades. In some large corporations, "vice president" is effectively the _lowest_ level of senior management; above mere vice presidents come entire layers of senior vice presidents, executive vice presidents, and CxOs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... said Burwell, vice president, European Union, at the Atlantic Council.

In this use, "vice president, European Union" is the position within the Atlantic Council which Burwell holds. Read it as:

> ... said Burwell, [Atlantic Council vice president, *(for the)* European Union and Special Initiatives](http://www.atlanticcouncil.org/about/experts/list/frances-g-burwell).